# tar: can't create directory 'sqljdbc_7.2/': Permission denied tar: can't open 'sqljdbc_7.2/': Is a directory

Tags: linux, docker, tar

I am trying to copy a file and then uncompress it in a docker file with these comands.

```
#MSSQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER INSTALL
COPY sqljdbc_7.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz /camunda/lib/
WORKDIR /camunda/lib
RUN tar -xf sqljdbc_7.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz
ENV CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar
ARG CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/tmp/sqljdbc_7.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar
RUN echo $CLASSPATH
```

but i get this error:

> tar: can't create directory 'sqljdbc_7.2/': Permission denied tar:
>   can't open 'sqljdbc_7.2/': Is a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `ADD` this will `untar` the file for you:

```
ADD sqljdbc_7.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz /camunda/lib/
```

and remove the following from `Dockerfile`:

```
WORKDIR /camunda/lib
RUN tar -xf sqljdbc_7.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz
```

From The Docs:

> If  is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format
>   (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory.